# using scanner class to average numbers in java

Tags: java, max, args

I am using a scanner class to average numbers together. I am using a method to do the averaging. I do not want the program to run if there are more than 20 args. I cant seem to get this to work. I am very new at java and trying to learn.

I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class programTwo {


    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double x = 0.00d;

        if (args != null) {
            System.out.println ("Enter your numbers to be averaged. Remember no more than 20!:");
            x = scan.nextInt();

            if (x <= 21) {
                System.out.println("Please do not add more than 20 numbers");   
            }  
       } else {
       }

    }

    public double average(double [] values) {
        double average = 0.0;
        if ((values != null) && (values.length > 0)) {
            for (double value : values) {
                average += value;
            }
        average /= values.length; 
        }
        return average;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why's x a dobule BTW, if you're reading int's into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution (cleaning up a lot of your code as well) that gets all the numbers on one line after the start of the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class programTwo {


    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double values[] = new double[20];
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println ("Enter your numbers to be averaged. Remember no more than 20!:");
        String inputs = scan.nextLine();
        scan = new Scanner(inputs); // create a new scanner out of our single line of input
        while(scan.hasNextDouble())
        {
            if(count == 20)
            {
                System.out.println("You entered too many numbers! Fail.");
                return;
            }
            values[count] = scan.nextDouble();
            count += 1;
        }

        System.out.println("Your average is: " + average(values, count));
    }

    public static double average(double [] values, int count) {
        double average = 0.0;
        for (double value : values) {
            average += value;
        }
        average /= count;

        return average;
    }

}
```

I got thinking you might want to use the args that are passed to main, since you use a null check, so you want to run your program like this:

```
java programTwo num1 num2 num3 num4 num5
```

etc. If that's the case, we have another solution:

```
class programTwo {


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        if(args.length > 20)
        {
            System.out.println("You entered too many numbers! Fail.");
            return;
        }
        double values[] = new double[args.length];
        for(int i=0; i< args.length; ++i)
            values[i] = Double.valueOf(args[i]);

        System.out.println("Your average is: " + average(values));
    }

    public static double average(double [] values) {
        double average = 0.0;
        for (double value : values) {
            average += value;
        }
        average /= values.length;

        return average;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just run a while loop that breaks when 20 "args" is met or until a break like `-1` is entered. Then if you are taking double values, you should use `x = scan.nextDouble()`. You also do not have a place where you are inserting the values into your array. At the end of your while loop you could put `x` into an array of doubles.

```
private double x;
private double Foo[] = new Foo[20];
private int this = 0; //Your counter

while(this < 20 && x != -1)
{
   x = scan.nextDouble();
   Foo[this++] = x;

}
```

Then carry out your `public double Average` by adding up the values in the array and dividing by (double)this

Answer (score 0):

The `args != null` check is unnecessary. One way to accomplish what you want is to accept numbers `while` the scanner has a next number (`scanner.hasNext()` perhaps) and `break` if the number of inputs thus far is less than 20. Since the number of double numbers is unknown, you're better off using an ArrayList.

`List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>();`

and calling the add method on `doubles`

`doubles.add(x);`
Then pass this to a method that averages the values in the arraylist.

Comment: Or just add a counter in that while loop (or use for).